# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard has stopped working

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-18

Am trying to use the Import and Export Wizard within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (right click database name > Tasks > Import Data) but immediately get this error;

[SQL Server Import and Export Wizard has stopped working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Akav.png)

This process has been working fine until this week when IT have upgraded us from MSSMS v17.6 to v18.9 (component and version info below)

SQL Server Management Studio                    15.0.18382.0

SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)             16.100.46337.53

Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools        15.0.19535.0

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)         10.0.19041.1

Microsoft MSXML                                 3.0 6.0

Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000

Operating System                                10.0.19044

IT are unable to troubleshoot and resolve the problem, but I'm guessing something is wrong with the install of the newer version of MSSMS. Any ideas or assistance to aid resolution gratefully received.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading SSMS?

Comment: @Charlieface I suspect that's what caused it.

Comment: Have your IT team checked the Application logs in Event Viewer? There are sometimes useful messages in there from DTSWizard.exe containing codes that can point you in the correct direction. Also, what type of file/s are you trying to import when this happens?

Comment: Also... SSMS 15.0.18382.0? That's a pretty old release (April 15, 2021). Why aren't they installing something current?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

@Charlieface we're at the mercy of our IT department, we don't have any admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning I'll ask them to check thanks. Am trying to import an .xlsx file but I don't even get to the stage that asks for the file location it just errors immediately after selecting Import Data from Tasks. We're a large multinational company, software releases are always miles behind the latest available! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, too. I read some threads saying that if you install SQL Server Data Tool, the wizard and SQL Job property window stop working altogether. Launching the wizard within Visual Studio works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know I might be resurrecting this, but I had a similar error today.

Installing the [KB5027505](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate6) from Microsoft fixed the issue.